# Structural Directive on element with routerLinkActive not working

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a custom directive used on the same element that has routerLinkActive.

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" *wpHasAnyPermission="[newAuthority(permEnum.USER_CREATE, levelEnum.ACCOUNT_OWN)]">
    <a id="createUser" routerLink="users/create"><i
    class="icon-plus-circle2"></i>Create a New User</a>
</li>
```

When I navigate to the routerLink specified above, I get `inline template caused by: Maximum call stack size exceeded` errors. If I remove the custom directive, the problem does not occur.

Not sure whats going here. Any hints on how to debug ?

I'm using ng 2.4.7, router 3.4.7

Directive

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[wpHasAnyPermission]'
})
export class HasAnyPermissionDirective {

    private authorities: Authority[];

    constructor(private principal: Principal, private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    }

    @Input()
    set wpHasAnyPermission(value: Authority[]) {
        this.authorities = <Authority[]> value;
        this.updateView();
        // Get notified each time authentication state changes.
        this.principal.getAuthenticationState().subscribe((identity) => this.updateView());
    }

    private updateView(): void {
        this.principal.hasAnyPermission(this.authorities).subscribe((result) => {
            this.viewContainerRef.clear();
            if (result) {
                this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Authority

```
export class Authority {
    constructor(public permission: PermissionType,
                public level: PermissionLevel) {

    }

    static of(permission: PermissionType, level: PermissionLevel): Authority {
        return new Authority(permission, level);
    }
}
```

Following function is in the component ts of the html.

```
newAuthority(perm: PermissionType, level: PermissionLevel): Authority {
    return Authority.of(perm, level);
}
```

It is now working when I assign directive value as `[{'permission': PermissionType.USER_CREATE, 'level': PermissionLevel.ACCOUNT_OWN}]`. However, I want to use a function so its easy to define permissions in HTML.

Comment: Have you tried search other questions of 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'? Maybe you need to post your directive code.

Comment: Yeah I've searched a lot. I have been debugging this for at least 8 hrs already..

Comment: Can you post your directive code?

Comment: When you use function you are returning new object every time

Comment: And how is that a problem ?

Comment: Here code is similar https://plnkr.co/edit/Eg1ZP67Yu49YQ0nAdwJe?p=preview

Comment: If you use promise or http then when it will resolved new change detection cycle starts. And setter will be called because you're returning new object. Then you shedule new task(promise or http call) after that new change detection cycle starts... So zone never gets stable

Comment: What would be the best solution given my scenario ? I really like to define them with a function instead of the working way I mentioned at the end of the post

Comment: @yurzui, assigning to a component variable is the only option ?